# Add or Upload files to Files Tab in Microsoft Teams File Tab

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to use the Microsoft Graph API to upload files under a Team's File Tab.

Can anyone help here which endpoints and in which sequence I need to use from Microsoft Graph API.

Thanks

Comment: The Files tab in channel is nothing it linked to SharePoint site default folder, Please take a look at [Upload Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) This API restricted to file size to 4MB. if you want to upload greater than 4MB you need to upload the file in stream or chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Files tab in channel is nothing it linked to SharePoint site default folder, Please take a look at [Upload Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) This API restricted to file size to 4MB. if you want to upload greater than 4MB you need to upload the file in stream or chunks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Graph API for this task.

Start with the [Microsoft Teams API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-concept-overview), which has a pretty good introduction and a 4 minute video.

Your next step is the [Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0). It's a big API, so rather than attempting to read it all I suggest you go straight to the [portion specific to Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[Uploading small files below 4 MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is a bit simpler than [uploading larger files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0).

You can also cheat a little, depending on what you are trying to do. Teams is really based on SharePoint for a lot of the stuff it does. So you can also use the [SharePoint API to upload files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery) to the SP site that is operating behind Teams.

There are code examples in the documentation to get you started.